# How do I connect two virtual machines in VMware player?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, virtual-machine, vmware

How do I connect two virtual machines in VMware player? I mean network connectvity and my host is XP and my my virtual machines are 2003 & 2008 Server respectively.

Please give your valuable suggestions